# Развёртывание и публикация WPF приложения с базой данных

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, публикация-приложений

Есть проект WPF приложения, с подключённой локальной БД по средством модели ADO.NET.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В начальном окне идёт авторизация пользователя (таблица пользователей в бд). После правильно введённых данных, по нажатию по кнопке **Войти** открывается следующее окно и т.д.

Для переноса приложения на другой компьютер опубликовал проект через сам VS, где создался .exe файл с установщиком приложения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки и последующего запуска приложения, по нажатию на кнопку **Войти** приложение вылетает не выдавая никаких ошибок. Как оказалось в конечную папку publicApp не переносится БД, собственно отчего и снимается. Как в установщик добавить локальную БД я так и не разобрался.

Comment: ado.net - это не БД, а компонент C#, который позволяет управлять базами данных. Сами базы данных существуют разные, они как минимум бывают в виде сервера, а бывают в виде простых локальных файлов (например SQLite одна из таких). Собственно от этого и надо плясать. Если у вас, как говорите, "подключённой локальной БД", то скорей всего на вашем компьютере запущен сервер, и тут как бы, что собрались в установщик запихивать? Клиент должен установить аналогичный сервер, залить туда снимок вашей базы, и так далее, ну или подключиться к вашей базе, на вашем компьютере.

Comment: Если речь идет про базы в виде файлов, то вопрос все тот-же, чего хотите запихивать в установщик? Ведь база обычно создается локально при помощи миграций, а не переносятся в виде файлов. Так что, как понимаете, вы в вопросе упустили очень важную деталь, без которой дать ответ довольно трудно, ибо гадание на кофейной гуще... Ну и думаю, что уже сами поняли свой косяк, и поняли, что база это не просто файлик на диске...

Comment: хорошо, как мне положить .mdf в сборку?

Comment: `.mdf` - это файл SQL Server'a (ключевое тут сервер), то есть, вы должны установить на другом компьютере SQL Server, восстановить там этот .mdf, в своем приложении поменять Connection String, где указывается информация нового SQL Server'a, и уже потом ваше приложение будет работать. Ну или у вас на одном компьютере постоянно должен быть запущен SQL Server и настроен на удаленное подключение, тогда Connection String должен быть указан на ваш внешний IP (или IP вашей сети). В любом случае, вы походу не понимаете, что `.mdf` это не просто файлик с данными, это часть сервера!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ что поменять в Connection String, чтобы БД открывалось на другом компе, куда собственно и устанавливается приложение, без удалённых соединений
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|LocalDirectory|\guestHouseGdb.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Вы понимаете суть вообще базы? Повторю, SQL Server - это сервер, некоторое приложение, которое висит на одном компьютере, и к которому можно подключиться удаленном. Это не просто файлик с данными, если вам нужен именно файлик с данными, то смотрите в сторону SQLite. Чтоб на другом компьютере ваше приложение находило базу, оно должно подключиться **удаленно** к вашему другому компьютеру, либо иметь свою локальную базу (свой установленный SQL Server с вашем набором данных). Строка подключения для удаленного соединения такая: `Server=myAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUser;Password=myPass;`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно ли упаковать это в установщик?

Comment: Что вы упаковывать собрались? Ну запихнете вы этот файл в установщик, ок, будет у вас рядом с приложением еще и `.mdf` файл, дальше что? Кто будет устанавливать саму программу SQL Server? А кто будет восстанавливать там базу? Ваш установщик? Клиенту этот файл бесполезен, он не должен там быть. Повторю, хотите базу из одного файлика, который будет переносим - SQLite вам в помощь, перепишите код на него, будет вам один файл, ну а чтоб он сам создавался - читайте про миграции и EF, а не ADO.NET.